# Theano is missing modules

Tags: anaconda, theano

I am on windows 64bit, I have installed anaconda, and managed to create an environment with python 2.7

I have numpy, pylearn2, theano, and every package is built properly

I have been able to import all these modules, however I get some very esoteric messages when I try to complete the model, like

```
ImportError: Could not import pylearn2.models.softmax_regression but could import pylearn2.models. Original exception: No module named dnn
```

Then I tried to actually find the package in the installation, but inside the cuda folder, there is no module named dnn. Looking at github, I see that it should be there.

Why is theano missing modules? I installed using conda install theano, and it gave some suggestions, I have managed to pick the correct one.

I have uninstalled and installed theano many time, I can import it but I can never get the proper modules.

What is going wrong?

Comment: The error relates to PyLearn2. What makes you think the problem is with Theano?

Comment: It is because when I actually try to import pylearn2.models.softmax_regression, then I get the following error 
"from theano.sandbox.cuda.dnn import dnn_available, dnn_pool
ImportError: No module named dnn"

The module isn't even physically present in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a few days of search, it seems like Theano installed from anaconda is missing a lot of modules. However, installing theano by cloning the repository with

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

seems to resolve the issue. Since windows normally does not have git, it can be easily installed (seems to take care of the environment's path variable) from here

```
https://git-scm.com/download/win
```