# Missing modules in Theano 1.0.4: "tanh", "shared"

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I know that Theano is considered out-dated, but I am trying to replicate some research results in DL topic modeling. This is the code: https://github.com/krenova/DeepLearningTopicModels

There are issues with Theano modules not being found (Theano v. 1.0.4; environment: Mac OS 11.3, Anaconda 2.0.1, Python 3.8, 3.7 and 2.7):
module 'theano' has no attribute 'shared'
module 'theano' has no attribute 'tanh'

I have also tried to downgrade Theano, but the same problem occurs with 1.0.1, 1.0.2, and 1.0.3.

I tried to follow this suggestion here and re-installed from source and using pip, but no luck.
[Theano is missing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283995/theano-is-missing-modules)

Does anyone know what happened to these modules? Have they been moved somewhere else?

Comment: Not a theano user myself, but my first try would be to try an even earlier version. The git you linked was last updated 03/2017 and theano was at version 0.9 at the time

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I went to back to 0.9.0, 0.8.2 and 0.8.0. All of these versions are giving me clang compilation errors. As I am expected to present some results, this is the point where I will not bother any further trying to reproduce these results.